# Как получить ID заказа на странице благодарности в WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте. Хочу использовать плагин Google Customer Reviews for WooCommerce. В его коде есть такие строчки:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'ecr_gcr_scripts');

function ecr_gcr_scripts($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    ?><!-- BEGIN GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn"
  async defer>
</script>

<script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": <?php echo get_option('ecr_merch_id'); ?>,
          "order_id": "<?php echo $order_id; ?>",
          "email": "<?php echo $order->billing_email; ?>",
          "delivery_country": "<?php echo $order->billing_country; ?>",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order->order_date.' + '.(int)get_option('ecr_delivery_days').' days')); ?>",
          "opt_in_style": "<?php echo get_option( 'ecr_optin_style' ); ?>"
        });
     });
  }
</script>
<!-- END GCR Opt-in Module Code -->

<!-- BEGIN GCR Language Code -->
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: '<?php echo get_option( 'ecr_gcr_lang' ); ?>'
  };
</script>
<!-- END GCR Language Code -->
<?php
}
```

Но так как используется плагин Saphali WC Lite, где указано, что после оплаты перенаправлять на страницу благодарности, то данный код опроса Google соответственно там не выводится, так как на той странице не задействован хук `woocommerce_thankyou`. Конечно, я могу туда поместить `do_action('woocommerce_thankyou');`, но это не спасёт ситуацию, так как $order_id на этой странице неизвестен уже.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить в этой ситуации? С какой стороны копнуть, чтобы вывести данный опрос на странице благодарности?

Answer (score 1):

Должно вот так сработать, попробуйте:

```
$order_id = WC()->order->id;
```

Ну, а куда эту строчку вставить, вы сами найдете. Из вопроса не вполне понятно.

Comment: Спасибо! Но на тот момент я вышел из положения [так](https://pastebin.com/iNB8D19N).